# Variable Not Recognized When Data Binding Attempted

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
<%for (int i = 1; i <= MessageList.Count; i++)
                   {
                       switch (LevelList[i-1])
                       {
                           case 0:%>
                            <div class="well offset1" style="width:80%">
                                <h1><%= MessageList[i - 1].Header%></h1>
                                <p><%= MessageList[i - 1].Body%></p>
                                <ul>
                                    <li style="display:inline">Likes: <%= MessageList[i - 1].NumberOfLikes%></li>
                                    <li style="display:inline">Replies: <%= MessageList[i - 1].NumberOfReplies%></li>
                                </ul>
                                <ul>
                                    <li style="display:inline"><asp:Button ID="LikeButton" messID="<%# MessageList[i-1].MessageID %>" runat="server" Text="Like" /></li>
                                    <li style="display:inline"><asp:Button ID="ReplyButton" messID="<%# MessageList[i-1].MessageID %>" runat="server" Text="Reply" /></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <%break;
```

My problem is with the "messID" in this part:

```html
<li style="display:inline"><asp:Button ID="LikeButton" messID="<%# MessageList[i-1].MessageID %>" runat="server" Text="Like" /></li>
```

At first I was attempting to pass a variable to the codebehind using `messID="<%= calculated value%>"` and using `Button.Attribute["messID"]` to access this variable, however, instead of passing the calculated variable as a string this passed a string that looked `<%= calculated variable%>`. After some research I found out that the `<%` could not be used with asp controls. So now I am attempting to use the `<%#` tag and `DataBind()`, however, now whatever is inside the `<%#` tags is not recognizing the variable `i` which is part of the `forloop`. Why does this happen?

Comment: try adding quotes messID=' "<%# MessageList[i-1].MessageID %>" '

Comment: Didn't work. The string that is being passed now looks like "\"<%# MessageList[i-1].MessageID %>\""

Comment: hmmm have you tried this messID=' <%# MessageList[i-1].MessageID %>'

Comment: That didn't work either. Now "i" is not being recognized again. Is there perhaps a different way of doing what I'm trying to do? All I want to do is to procedural generate buttons on my page, each of which will correspond to a message. When a user clicks on one of the reply buttons, it takes them to a page where they can write their response. For the page to know which message they are responding to, I need to pass it a Message ID as a QueryString. So each button should have a different value for the Querystring variable.

Answer (score 0):

Why not you just use html a tag?

> All I want to do is to procedural generate buttons on my page, each of which will correspond to a message. When a user clicks on one of the reply buttons, it takes them to a page where they can write their response.

change

```
<li style="display:inline"><asp:Button ID="LikeButton" messID="<%# MessageList[i-1].MessageID %>" runat="server" Text="Like" /></li>
```

to

```
<li style="display:inline"><a href="xxx.aspx?id=<%=MessageList[i-1].MessageID %>">Like</a></li>
```

Comment: Oh yeah that's what I ended up using anyways. I would just prefer not using it because I have to send the user to another page for it to work.

Comment: Try using some javascript components,like artdialog  or fancybox.